# Inductors at a DC motor's terminals

Tags: dc-motor, inductor

While tearing down an RC toy to scavenge the DC motors, I found an unusual circuit attached to the motor that turns the car right or left. It seems that it has two inductors but I am not exactly sure. Any idea what the purpose of this board in such a minimalist application can be?

[image: dc motor]

Comment: It's likely EMI/noise suppression.

Comment: Wow, they were desperate to get this thing quieted down. I’ve not seen a PCB-based suppression network for a little motor like that yet!

Comment: Because of the filtering symmetry, I'd guess this motor was driven by an H-bridge (allows the motor to turn clockwise/counter-clockwise from a logic state).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic brushed DC motor.

Something to know about brushed motors is that they're *incredibly* electrically noisy. They create all kinds of noise from arcing in the brushes.

So you shield the noise as well as you can, when necessary. As this is for a radio-controlled device, it runs a risk of interfering with the radio circuitry, so I'd say it's prudent to do at least a little noise filtering here. So, inductors, as well as the capacitors that are also on that PCB. You'll note the PCB is also grounded to the motor case, which also acts as shielding for radiated noise from the motor.

Comment: I don’t see which signal is being filtered here, is it the incoming control signal from the main board?

Comment: (The place to add capacitors is between alternator segments, right on the rotor. Don't forget to secure mechanically…) The signal getting filtered is generated by the motor.

Comment: It's not a signal. You're keeping noise out of your power lines.

Comment: @greybeard Sure, but a pi filter outside the motor helps too, at least.

Comment: Noise current driven by motors into power lines is insidious as it permeates the rest of the device, and preferentially flows through decoupling capacitors that try to keep sensitive circuitry quiet.